# Hotjar alternative for non-SAAS product

Tags: user-interface, visual-design

I've had a question about Hotjar for a while now and I haven't been able to find a solution, so I hope you can help me.

My problem is that I want to use Hotjar in an on-premise ERP system (non-saas), where the URLs of our customers are not the same, something like: sistemajean.com.br, jean.system.com.br, so on, but they are all the same system, the customer can change the URL according to their preference.

So it doesn't make sense to install Hotjar because it would have to be done one by one, since it only maps one URL. But I need to have general information about all the systems.

I've been racking my brains for months about this and I can't find a solution. Do you know of any tool that can solve this? Some kind of "Hotjar for non-SAAS software".

*I know there's an option in Hotjar where you put it in: URL ends in, URL starts with, etc. But it still won't help me because the URLs don't follow a pattern.